# The second UINotification not not show in background after showed the first notification

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ibeacon

I'm developing an iBeacon app. I have two beacons.

Firstly, when the app did enter background (locked screen)
- if app found the first iBeacon I show a notification
- Continue i use the second iBeacon and my iphone doesn't show notification
- But when i active screen so app reactive and show notification for the second ibeacon

I don't know why iOS doesn't show a notification for the second iBeacon after showed it for the first iBeacon in background status?

Comment: You might post your code and describe your beacon identifiers to help us help you.

Comment: Check whether the method is fired twice or once. Sometimes, it's not about the problem of sending notifications. It's about whether the second beacon triggered the sending method.

Answer (score 1):

If both beacons are part of the same `CLBeaconRegion`, your app will only be triggered in the background on first detection.  You can change this by defining two regions, one to cover each beacon.